# Zero Padding in the DFT domain using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to generate a real random sequence for M = 128.
x[n] -> { x<sub>0</sub> x<sub>1</sub> x<sub>2</sub> ... x<sub>127</sub>}

Also I need to zero pad this x[n] with 128 zeroes as
x<sub>e</sub>[n] -> { x<sub>0</sub> x<sub>1</sub> x<sub>2</sub> ... x<sub>127</sub> 0 0 0 0 ……… 0} i.e N = 256

Then I need to take DFT of x[n] -> X<sup>F</sup>[k].

At end I need to display magnitude and Phase spectrum.

How this can be done ? Please help. I want them as am working on Zero Padding in the DFT domain.

Comment: This is very basic Matlab. What have you tried? Post the code you have and where you got stuck

Comment: @LuisMendo I am very new to MATLAB. And require it in my project. This is just a part of it.